# how to return function pointer of compound function in c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, c++14

for example, how to turn below code in matlab to a c++ equivalence?

```
function g = Transform(funct, y)

         h = @(x) funct(x) +y;
         g = @(x) sign(h(x));
 end
```

the above code takes in a function named "funct" and a input value "y". It outputs a new (transformed) function named g.

a usage of this in matlab would be

```
function main()
  for i = 1:5
     y = rand();
     funct = Tranform(funct,y);
  end

 disp(funct(1.27)); % after transformed 5 times

end

function z = funct(x)
     z = x;
end
```

Comment: Matlab is not strongly typed while C++ is. Suggest you limit arguments to specific types and add a sample where you call g(). templates with variadic arguments might offer increased flexibility too.

Comment: Argh, I am not going to adapt the code below now. The change came too late ;)

Comment: Well, the idea is the same, but you will have to do the changes now. This is not a code writing service as nobody is paided here. Please consider to post the complete question next time if it makes a difference for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it looks a little more messy. For this you can use lambda functions together with std::function like so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>


template <typename T> int sgn(T val)
{
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

std::function<int(double)> transform(std::function<double(double)> funct, double y )
{
    std::function<int(double)> h = [=](double x) -> int
    {
        return sgn(funct(x) + y);
    };

    return h;
}


int main()
{
    auto f = [](double x) -> double { return x + 5.; };
    auto res = transform(f, 5.);
    std::cout << res(-15.) << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs:

> res(-10) -> 0
>
> res(> -10) -> 1
>
> res(< -10) -> -1

Comment: I think got the gist of your code, will try to implement the method. Thank you!

Comment: I have a question. can I cast the function<double(double)> to a function pointer type like double (*funct_ptr) (double) ? because I eventually want a function pointer.

Comment: You can use a std::function like a c-style function pointer and you also should use std::function before c-style function pointer if there is not a really good reason. However, you can also use the method target() to get the underlying pointer (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target).